# reference c++ project using OpenCV in a c# project (windows universal) vs2015

Tags: c#, c++, windows, opencv, universal

I have a C# Project (universal windows) referencing a c++ Project (universal windows). In the c++ project I have logic to recognition using openCV library. The compilation is ok and I add the using to namespace of c++ in the c# class, and I create a object with c++ class, and the build is ok but when I run the app it's crashed.

[image: Screenshot]

> An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in AdMobilizeNetTest.exe but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

I set Project configuration to use openCV

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Now there are nuget packages available for all the opencv libraries and it's pretty straightforward to use them in a C++ UWP app or in c++ runtime component. They are still in pre-release though, So make sure to check the 'include pre-release' option. Hope this helps.